# multiboot header doesn't work in boot file

Tags: assembly, kernel, grub

I'm trying to write a multiboot kernel compliant using the grub (legacy) specification , here is the content of my boot.s (written with the gnu as)

```
#include "boot.h"
    .code32
    .globl start
    .type start, @function
    .extern kernel_main
    .type kernel_main, @function
    .bss
    .comm stack, STACK_SIZE

    .section .mboot
    .align 4
    .long MBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC
    .long MBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS
    .long MBOOT_CHECKSUM
        .text
start:
    movl $(stack + STACK_SIZE) , %esp
    cli
    call kernel_main
    sti
    hlt
    jmp .
```

The boot.h file content some definition for grub:

```
#ifndef _BOOT_H_
#define _BOOT_H_
#define MBOOT_PAGE_ALIGN 1<<0
#define MBOOT_MEM_INFO 1<<1
#define MBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC 0x1BADB002
#define MBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS MBOOT_PAGE_ALIGN | MBOOT_MEM_INFO
#define MBOOT_CHECKSUM -( MBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC + MBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS)
#define STACK_SIZE 0x4000
#endif /* _BOOT_H_ */
```

I also set up the linker like this:

```
ENTRY(start)
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386)
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386")
SECTIONS
{
    . = 1M;
    .mboot ALIGN(4K) :
    {
        *(.mboot)

    }
    .text ALIGN(4K) :
    {
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata)
    }
    .data ALIGN(4K) :
    {
        *(.data)
    }
    .bss ALIGN(4K) :
    {
        *(.bss)
    }
}
```

For the moment , my kernel_main simply return the value 0x01 which i'm expecting in the %eax register, however when i execute the kernel with:

```
qemu -kernel kernel.bin -monitor stdio
```

and then issue the command `info registers` in qemu , i always find a value of 18 for %eax. So my questions are: is my boot.s file correctly defined to be grub compliant? and why the value 18 in %eax instead of 0x01?

Answer (score 0):

Your image is most likely correct - QEMU will throw an error if it's not multiboot-compliant. `eax` is probably used by an interrupt handler after your call to kernel_main, because you enable interrupts with `sti`.

Comment: Even though i swap the `sti` instruction out, i have always the same value in `eax` , i've even add a small video driver to output some text on screen but i see nothing. @Martijn

Comment: Hook up GDB to QEMU, step through the instructions and track eax.

Comment: The problem was not my boot.s file,